# change url without redirecting using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, redirect

I would like to know how to change the url without redirecting like on this website http://dekho.com.pk/ads-in-lahore
when we click on tabs the url changes but the page dosent reload completely. There are other questions on stackoverflow indicating that it is not possible but i would like to know how the above mentioned website have implemented it.
Thanks

Comment: On the link you mentioned, same webservice is called but with different parameters.

Comment: [`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). There's also jQuery in there, but that particular technique has got to be. push state with a fall back for older browsers.

Comment: You can also use window.location.hash and modify http://url.com/page#hash.

Comment: [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) seems to be a fairly comprehensive take on the `pushState` technique. See the [demos](http://balupton.github.com/history.js/demo/).

Answer (score 242, accepted):

use `pushState`:

```
window.history.pushState(data, title, url);
```

LE: since modern browsers changed behaviour, use `replaceState` instead:

```
window.history.replaceState(data, title, url);
```

Comment: refer link for more details http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: `window.history.replaceState(data, title, url);` is also useful

Comment: wow, this works like a charm!

Comment: doesnt work in firefox - "SecurityError: The operation is insecure."

Comment: @Pierre thanks, window.history.replaceState(data, title, url); is especially useful if you do not want to mess with the actual history, so when the user clicks back they go to the previous page, not the previous url you pushed.

Comment: What does LE stand for?

Comment: @KevinWheeler :) Later Edit :)

Answer (score 9):

If you want to know exactly what they using, it's **Backbone.js** (see lines `4574` and `4981`). It's all mixed up in there with the jQuery source, but these are the relevant lines of the [annotated `Backbone.Router` source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-108) documentation page:

The [support checks](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1029):

```
  this._wantsPushState = !!this.options.pushState;
  this._hasPushState = !!(this.options.pushState && window.history && window.history.pushState);
```

The `route` function:

```
route: function(route, name, callback) {
    Backbone.history || (Backbone.history = new History);

    if (!_.isRegExp(route)) route = this._routeToRegExp(route);

    if (!callback) callback = this[name];

    Backbone.history.route(route, _.bind(function(fragment) {
        var args = this._extractParameters(route, fragment);

        callback && callback.apply(this, args);

        this.trigger.apply(this, ['route:' + name].concat(args));

        Backbone.history.trigger('route', this, name, args);
    }, this));

    return this;
},
```

Choosing between [hash and push state](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1043)s:

```
// Depending on whether we're using pushState or hashes, and whether
// 'onhashchange' is supported, determine how we check the URL state.
if (this._hasPushState) {
    Backbone.$(window).bind('popstate', this.checkUrl);
} else if (this._wantsHashChange && ('onhashchange' in window) && !oldIE) {
    Backbone.$(window).bind('hashchange', this.checkUrl);
} else if (this._wantsHashChange) {
    this._checkUrlInterval = setInterval(this.checkUrl, this.interval);
}​
```

More on what they're up to:

```
// If we've started off with a route from a `pushState`-enabled browser,
// but we're currently in a browser that doesn't support it...
if (this._wantsHashChange && this._wantsPushState && !this._hasPushState && !atRoot) {
    this.fragment = this.getFragment(null, true);
    this.location.replace(this.root + this.location.search + '#' + this.fragment);

    // Return immediately as browser will do redirect to new url
    return true;

    // Or if we've started out with a hash-based route, but we're currently
    // in a browser where it could be `pushState`-based instead...
} else if (this._wantsPushState && this._hasPushState && atRoot && loc.hash) {
    this.fragment = this.getHash().replace(routeStripper, '');
    this.history.replaceState({}, document.title, this.root + this.fragment);
}

if (!this.options.silent) return this.loadUrl();
```

And the [coup 'd grace](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1132):

```
// If pushState is available, we use it to set the fragment as a real URL.
if (this._hasPushState) {
     this.history[options.replace ? 'replaceState' : 'pushState']({}, document.title, url);
}
```

You should read the annotated Backbone.js link I provided at the top. Very informative.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.it was very informative. i dont know backbone yet so i am going for the pushstate as it fulfills all my needs.

Comment: Backbone.js is built around it's router, as it's a "single page app". Although you may not be experienced enough yet to see it in my answer above, that's *exactly* what Backbone.js is doing, as well has graceful degradation (for those who don't have browsers that support it). See my link in comment under your question; I'd use a library like https://github.com/balupton/History.js/, not roll your own. Unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: I am using History.js as i am a newb :)