# How do I change content without changing pages (non-hashed URLs)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, navigation

I know how to change content of a page using AJAX and remote loading of content. However, take a look at [UStream's new layout](http://ustream.tv). Click on any video, and not only does the content change without changing the page itself... but the entire URL changes as well. How is this done?

I know how to do it using the hashtag in a URL, and using JavaScript to detect when the location's hash value has changed. For example, `site.com/#!/profile` to `site.com/#!/settings`. Any value after the `#!` part is loaded remotely.

But UStream doesn't use the hash symbol at all. How is this accomplished? What voodoo is at work here?

Comment: Try: https://github.com/aFarkas/history.js

Comment: @JaredFarrish That fork is better than the original?

Comment: @alex - Um, yeah, sure. This one? https://github.com/balupton/history.js Are you setting me up?

Comment: @alex - Are you there? Were you simply pointing out I didn't point back to the source, or did you have an actual problem with the link to aFarkas' fork?

Comment: @JaredFarrish No problem at all. I was just curious if it was recommended over the original (maybe I'd missed some discussion).

Comment: @alex - Ah, sorry, been sniped a few times today. Honestly, I don't know the answer. Seems there is some frisson in the history business, but to be honest, I got so many links by now, I'm wondering what's best. That was my best guess. Seems like there's another approach, but can't find it at the moment.

Comment: @alex - This was my answer on a previous (and not too distant) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446317/change-url-without-redirecting-using-javascript/12446647#12446647 (Backbone.js stuff, of course.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing the [HTML5 History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html).

Comment: This seems like the most likely method being employed by these sites. Good to know it's an HTML5 feature. Thanks!